# Typo3 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception "Warning: gzuncompress(): need dictionary"

Tags: php, database, typo3, ddev

I'm working for the first time with Typo3.

Unfortunately I always get the error message:

> **#1476107295 TYPO3\CMS\Core\Error\Exception**
>
> PHP Warning: gzuncompress(): need dictionary in
> /var/www/html/public/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Cache/Backend/Typo3DatabaseBackend.php
> line 157

I already tried to fix it like
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509163/php-warning-in-typo3databasebackend-line-158-after-updating-ddev-to-1-19?fbclid=IwAR3zIwsLuOltXY2o1JlqZn5f22G4M-hxH5U-3Dyc0u03wMfqsXtd9mBesqc) and it seemed to work for a moment after a *ddev restart* but on the second click to edit the page, the error message was back.

Here are some Screenshots.

[image: Error Message]

[image: AdditionalConfiguration.php]

Maybe you can find my Mistake.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the installtool you can set the compression level for backend and frontend.
The values are written then to the file tyo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php and are these:

```
$GLOALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['compressionLevel'] = 0;
$GLOALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['compressionLevel'] = 0;
```

I added the value 0, so after changing the values you have to clear the cache and should be able to access everything again.